# Create attribute option if not exists

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, eav

How would i create a dropdown attribute option if it does not already exist for an attribute?

For example, the following will not work correctly if the option values do not exist:

```
$productColors = array('sku_1' => 'red','sku_2' => 'blue','sku_3' => 'green');

foreach($productColors as $sku => $color) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $product->setData('color', $color)->save(); // This wont work if that option value is not alaready created

}
```

I now need a way to ensure the value is set properly

Answer (score 2):

You would need to check the attribute for the option you are adding, and if it doesn't exist, add it using `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.

```
<?php

foreach($productColors as $sku => $color) {

    addAttributeValue('color', $color);

}

function addAttributeValue($attributeCode, $attValue) {

    if (!attributeValueExists($attributeCode, $attValue)) {
        $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
        $attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
        $option['value']['option_name'][0] = $attValue;
        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
    }
}

function attributeValueExists($attribute, $value) {
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');
    $attribute_code = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attribute);
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
    $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $value) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This may need some tweaking for your particular situation, but the general idea works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$productColors = array('sku_1' => 'red','sku_2' => 'blue','sku_3' => 'green');

foreach($productColors as $sku => $color) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
        $optionId =  false;;
        $attributeCode =  'color';
        if ($color != '') {
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
            if ($attribute->getId() && $attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select') {
                $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                        ->setAttribute($attribute)
                        ->getAllOptions(false);
                $_existValue = false;
                foreach ($options as $option){
                    if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                        $_existValue = true;
                        $optionId = $option['value'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!$_existValue) {
                    $option = array('value' => array('option' => array($color)));
                    $attribute->setData('option', $option);
                    $attribute->save();
                    $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
                            ->setAttribute($attribute)
                            ->getAllOptions(false);
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        if (trim(strtolower($option['label'])) == trim(strtolower($color))) {
                            $optionId = $option['value'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if($optionId) {
            $product->setColor($optionId)
                ->setId($product->getId())
                ->save();
        }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for 'saving' a product or attribute? based on you event/observer you will want to put a validation before it such as product_validate_before. This will stop anything saving on the product form if that value wasn't chosen properly. If you need the code I can send you a snippet for you observer.